# Where is my loop going wrong?

Tags: python, loops

The brief I've been given - "Now write a program that calculates the minimum fixed monthly payment needed in order pay off a credit card balance within 12 months."

In essence what I've done is far, is code up something that will take a base value (10 for example), take it away from the credit card balance (taking into account the interest), and if the total number of months it takes to put the balance into a negative (e.g. paid off) is above 12, it adds to the 'minmonth' (amount to be paid off per month) until the number of months is equal to is or below 12.

What's happening instead is that it's now coming up with this and getting into a loop, and constantly going into the ''else', rather than only doing it once when the number of months is below 12. Excessively long for post - http://pastebin.com/yruGDKiP

Where am I going wrong? :/

```
balance = float(raw_input('Enter the outstanding balance on your creditcard: '))
interest = float(raw_input('Enter the annual credit card interest rate as a decimal:        '))

startbalance = balance
minmonth = 1000
months = 0
monthlyinterest =  interest / 12

while(balance > 0):
   balance = balance * (1 + monthlyinterest) - minmonth
   months = months + 1

   if(months > 12):
       months = 0
       minmonth = minmonth + 10
       balance = startbalance

   else:
      print 'RESULT!'
      print 'Total amount to pay per month would be'
      print minmonth
      print 'Total months to pay'
      print months
```

Comment: Clearly balance has become negative before months reach 12. Think about the logic statements in your code. Study the flow through the while and if. Is it really what you want?

Comment: Does you assignment insist you use trial and error type algorithm? Can you not just calculate the answer using mathematical formulae?

Comment: You need to think about how to do your own homework. We can solve this but you'll learn more if you do it yourself. Try stepping through the program in your mind. See if you can understand the observed behaviour.

Comment: The assignment isn't formal homework, I'm teaching myself Python via several online courses, which give you example assignments to do and such.

Comment: I've edited code to reflect the balance resetting and now I get this (constant loop). :/ http://pastebin.com/yruGDKiP

Comment: Do you know the formula for the sum of a geometric series?

Answer (score 1):

1. If you only want to show a result if the balance has, in fact, been paid off, then you need to check for whether the balance has been paid off before printing.
2. If you go 12 months without managing to pay off the balance, then to see if an increase in the payment will succeed, you need to reset the balance before starting the "simulation" again.

Try making a separate function that tests whether a given monthly payment will suffice, and calling that with gradually increasing values.

Although you really should just, you know, *do math* instead of this trial and error business

Comment: I seem to have figured it out thanks to your help, I appreciate it.

Comment: And yes, I realise I should 'do math', but being 16 I'm not fluent with geometric series algorithms sadly. Cheers though.

Comment: The math is not hard... do some research and see what you can dig up.

Answer (score 0):

```
months = 0

while(balance > 0):
   months = months + 1
  if(months < 12):
      months = 0
```

maybe you wanted to write months > 12 but not <

Comment: And also balance would need to be reset. But the print would run on the very first iteration.

Comment: Have edited code (and main post in turn) to reflect this. Thanks.